# Java Multiple Method Calls

Tags: java

My application has a `methodA` that is executed for a service request. Now we would like to send a list of requests instead of single request and for every request `methodA` has to be called or processed. I could put a basic loop and call the method like

```
public String findN(criteria criteriaList)  {
    .....................
    for( int i = 0; i < reqList.length; i++ )
    {
        Req req = reqList[i];
        methodA(req);
    }
}
```

Is there a better programming approach then just looping? Is there a design pattern that covers this aspect?

Comment: There is in Javascript, Scala, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(Request req : reqList) {
    MethodA(req);
}
```

Is the best Java offers currently.  More functional languages do this in one line, using methods like `.map`, `.foreach`, etc.

Comment: Java 8 will finally have some of that

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I was looking if there was a spring feature or any design pattern wherein without any loops it would just trigger calling the method for every item in the list.